# Why are duplicates of "Minecraft PE Invalid Server" questions not being deleted?

Tags: discussion

I have found at least four or five different questions that basically say, "I tried to join this MCPE server but it said 'invalid name.'" In my opinion, one of these two things should happen:

- Delete the duplicates
- Consolidate the answers into one question to prevent confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't delete duplicates. Duplicates are good, if they are set up so that eventually they lead to a question with GOOD answers! They give people more ways to find their way here and find out we have awesome information. [For more help on how SE handles dupes, this MSE post is handy.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Sometimes it means that multiple dupes get answers, but that's okay. No need to merge them - if we did our duping right, then the dupe target should be the one with the most awesome info. (And please, if you find a time when this is not the case, let us know, so we can make sure people get the best help we can provide.)

Comment: Well, actually, we DO delete duplicates. But the criteria to do so is more exacting than other closed questions.

Comment: Yeah, but in the general case, we don't delete on sight or anything.

Comment: So many duplicates of minecraft problems are, helpfully, titled "problem with minecraft" or some slight variation on that theme. They don't often have the same value as duplicates of other duplicate questions can in being "sign posts".

Comment: Having bazillion of duplicates, can be an indication of a problem, through.